# Weibull distribution is not a glm, why?

Tags: probability, generalized-linear-model, weibull-distribution, exponential-family

It is a generalized linear model with a linear combination of covariates related to the response via a canonical link function.

Why weibull distribution is not a glm?

Comment: I think you have nearly answered your own question by adding the "exponential-family" tag. The Weibull distribution is not a member of the exponential-family and hence not a glm. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Overview)